# Remove div has class error-message and show after parent div class styled-select

Tags: jquery

My Output is coming like

```
    <div class="styled-select">
        <div class="input select error">
            <select id="UserCountryId" class="form-error" name="data[User][country_id]">
            <option value="">(choose one)</option>
            <option value="243">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
            <div class="error-message">Country is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But Need Output like

```
    <div class="styled-select">
        <div class="input select error">
            <select id="UserCountryId" class="form-error" name="data[User][country_id]">
            <option value="">(choose one)</option>
            <option value="243">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="error-message">Country is required</div>
```

is that possible via jQuery or should i change my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.styled-select').each(function(index){
        var $error = $(this).find('.error-message').clone();
        $(this).find('.error-message').remove();
        $(this).after($error);
     });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2kq8v/3/)

Comment: But i want to remove from parent div who has class styled-select

Comment: This is not a good attitude to clone element which should be just relocated in the DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Here is *shorter* and *faster* solution:

```
$('.styled-select').each(function() {
    $('.error-message', this).insertAfter(this);
});
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/Z32NH/